# How to emulate a tap on a uiview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I come to a problem...
Here's it:

I add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to `self.view` (`self` is a `UIViewController`) and handle the tap event.

But I have another `UIView` which is a subview of `self.view`, and it has a reaction of "tap" gesture (`touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`).

**Problem** arises : When I tap on it, because `self.view` intercept the gesture, the `UIView` can't get the event. So is there a way to emulate a "tap", or to let go naturally in the action function?

---add---

[Forwarding UIGesture to views behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209998/forwarding-uigesture-to-views-behind) is a similar question, but in that case, it can pass a `UIGestureRecognizer` to subview.

in this case, I need to handle when the touch begins and when it ends, so it can't handle with a `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Or if I can adapt the functions with `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Oh I foget to add, The Tap actually passed to the UIView, because the "touchesCancelled" is called. Why is this function called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209998/forwarding-uigesture-to-views-behind

Comment: TouchesCancelled is called if the touch is interupted by the system, i.e. because of a low memory warning or an incoming phone call (see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesCancelled:withEvent: ).

It may however also be called if the system thinks the touch event should be handled by another view (i.e. if you start touching on a scrollview and the system detects that you are not starting a scroll event.)

Comment: I read the question above, but in that case, the subview has a function handle with "UIgestureRecognizer", which isn't suit for mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I solved it with passing it a `UIGesturerecognizer`, and used this method:
[How to replace TouchesBegan with UIGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628115/how-to-replace-touchesbegan-with-uigesturerecognizer)